# Excel 2003 doesn't undo after saving

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, undo

Every time I save changes on Excel, it doesn't allow me to undo the changes I did before saving. Is that the normal behaviour of Excel 2003 or I have some weird seetting done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the normal behaviour in Excel 2003. But 2007 finally allows undo-ing after saving.

Comment: Thanks. It bugs me because Word 2003 does allow undo after saving. I will need some work around.